# Why might a PHP-based HTTP request fail to allow chunked encoding?

Tags: php, http, chunked-encoding

I've got an XML-over-HTTP service that has been working quite well for a long time, and I've been asked to provide some sample PHP code to connect to it. I've written the code and it connects, etc. just fine, except that
it's waiting for the keep-alive timeout (5s) before completing.

When I connect using a Java-based client, I can see that Tomcat (through httpd) is using chunked encoding:

`DEBUG: Request properties:
DEBUG:   Accept-Charset: UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, *
DEBUG:   Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform
DEBUG:   Accept: application/xml, text/xml, text/plain
DEBUG:   User-Agent: My Awesome Java Client
DEBUG:   Pragma: no-cache
DEBUG:   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DEBUG:   Content-Type: application/xml
DEBUG: Received first response packet after 219ms
DEBUG: Dumping HTTP response headers
DEBUG:   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG:   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
DEBUG:   null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG:   Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
DEBUG:   Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG:   Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 15:33:13 GMT
DEBUG:   Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
DEBUG: Read response in 7ms`

When I use the PHP client, here's what I get in the response headers:

`array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=>
  string(35) "Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 15:37:01 GMT"
  [2]=>
  string(30) "Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100"
  [4]=>
  string(22) "Connection: Keep-Alive"
  [5]=>
  string(43) "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8"
}`

Note that there isn't any `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header.

I can confirm that the PHP client is making an HTTP/1.1 request (and
the response is using HTTP/1.1 as you can see) but chunked encoding
seems not to be in use, here.

I believe I am sending the same request headers from the PHP client.
Here's what the server is seeing:

`2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] ========== Request from x.y.113.203
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] host: example.com
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] content-length: 135
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] content-type: application/xml
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] user-agent: My Awesome PHP Client
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] accept: application/xml, text/xml, text/plain
2017-02-03 10:44:59,287 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] Accept-Charset: UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, *
2017-02-03 10:44:59,288 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2017-02-03 10:44:59,288 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform
2017-02-03 10:44:59,288 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] pragma: no-cache
2017-02-03 10:44:59,288 [catalina-exec-2] TRACE MyServlet- [1d] connection: keep-alive`

And the same from the Java client:

`2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] ========== Request from x.y.113.203
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e]  user-agent: My Awesome Java Client
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] content-type: application/xml
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] accept: application/xml, text/xml, text/plain
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] Accept-Charset: UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, *
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] pragma: no-cache
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] host:
example.com
2017-02-03 10:46:33,684 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] connection: keep-alive
2017-02-03 10:46:33,685 [catalina-exec-3] TRACE MyServlet- [1e] content-length: 135`

I'm using the same "call" payload and the response should be identical
for the two clients.

If I add `Connection: close` to the headers from the PHP client then
the call completes immediately without the 5-second delay.

PHP is documented to support chunked encoding, but the server doesn't
look like it's even trying to use chunked encoding, since the response
headers don't say anything about it. The PHP code looks like this:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => array('Content-Type: application/xml',
                          'User-Agent: My Awesome PHP Client',
                          'Accept: application/xml, text/xml, text/plain',
                          'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, *',
                          'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                          'Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform',
                          'Pragma: no-cache',

// NOTE: Connection: close makes multiple calls less efficient, but file_get_contents seems to stall otherwise
//                              'Connection: close'
'Connection: keep-alive',
        ),
        'follow_location' => 0, // Don't follow redirects
        'protocol_version' => '1.1',
        'ignore_errors' => TRUE, // Does not dump ugly errors to stderr
        'timeout' => 0.01, // TODO: adjustable
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $message,
    ),
    'ssl' => array(
        'disable_compression' => TRUE,
        'ciphers' => '!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DSS:!DES:!3DES:!SSLv2:!RC4:!MD5:ECDHE:ECDH',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Any ideas as to what might be happening? I believe if chunked-encoding is used, the client won't stall waiting for more information when the response is in fact complete.

Please note that the response must be either chunked or timed-out, because the dynamic and streaming nature of the response cannot have its `content-length` pre-computed and sent in an HTTP response header.

Comment: IME usually the host web server decides about chunking or not based on whether the CGI sets a content-length, whether the client advertises support for HTTP/1.1 or not etc.  If the server is emitting chunked responses without setting Transfer-Encoding: chunked, that would seem to be a bug in the server.  The server also needs to know when the CGI has stopped generating output so it can emit the terminating chunk (0 length).  Is this CGI or Fast-CGI?

Comment: @Adrien The server is Java-based ("Tomcat through httpd") and we never set a `Content-Length` header as mentioned at the end of the question. The server is *not* using chunked-encoding. Rather, I *want* the server to use chunked-encoding, but it's not.

Comment: This appears to be happening only with the PHP-based client. Using the exact same "call" (an identical XML document POSTed to the server with all the same request headers), the Java client ends up getting chunked-encoding and the PHP client does not. I can see no difference between what goes over the wire, so I'm at a loss to explain why the PHP client is causing the server to behave differently.

Comment: The only requirement for a server to send a chunked response is that the client advertise http/1.1 as it's mandatory to implement. You might need to wireshark it to see what is going on.  I guess it's possible php is messing up the response before you see it in the PHP script.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought: `HTTP/1.1` by definition supports chunked encoding. I've been avoiding Wireshark because we are using ECDHE-based TLS even in our development environments. I'll have to temporarily disable that to get a good wire capture.